# Uber Widget Login screen showing blank in iPhone but showing in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uber-api

I am trying to integrate the Uber Widget in my iPhone application (made in `Xcode Version 7.3.1` with language `Objective C`). Put all things as described in [Uber-ride-request-widget](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/ride-request-widget)
and [Github of Uber rides-ios-sdk](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk). Created all the credential which Uber need like `CLIENT_ID`, `Service Token` in [Uber Developer Account](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard). I have installed pod for Uber as they said:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'My_Project_Name' do
pod 'UberRides'
end
```

and ran `pod install` and successfully installed the `pod` and then

Set `info.plist` as they described:

```
    <key>UberClientID</key>
    <string>MY_APP_CLIENT_ID</string>
    <key>UberDisplayName</key>
    <string>MY_APP_NAME</string>
```

and

```
<key>UberCallbackURIs</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>URIString</key>
            <string>https://www.google.com</string>
            <key>UberCallbackURIType</key>
            <string>General</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

and also added following code in `NSExceptionDomains` within `NSAppTransportSecurity` keeping `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `true`

```
        <key>uber</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>uberauth</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
```

Now added following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`

```
// China based apps should specify the region
    [UBSDKConfiguration setRegion:RegionDefault];
    // If true, all requests will hit the sandbox, useful for testing
    [UBSDKConfiguration setSandboxEnabled:YES];
    // If true, Native login will try and fallback to using Authorization Code Grant login (for privileged scopes). Otherwise will redirect to App store
    [UBSDKConfiguration setFallbackEnabled:NO];
```

and Written following code to make the Uber Widget call:

```
id<UBSDKRideRequesting> behavior = [[UBSDKRideRequestViewRequestingBehavior alloc] initWithPresentingViewController: self];
    CLLocation *location4 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: 40.785695 longitude: -73.970208];

    CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: 40.791251 longitude: -73.977149];
    UBSDKRideParametersBuilder *builder = [[UBSDKRideParametersBuilder alloc] init];
    [builder setPickupLocation:location4];
    [builder setDropoffLocation:location2];
    UBSDKRideParameters *parameters = [builder build];
    UBSDKRideRequestButton *button1 = [[UBSDKRideRequestButton alloc] initWithRideParameters: parameters requestingBehavior: behavior];
    button1.center=self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
```

Now when I am running the app in `Simulator[Version 9.3 (SimulatorApp-645.9 CoreSimulator-209.19)]` it is showing like the following:

> [image: Simulator image for Uber Login]

But when running in device (iPhone 5s or 6 with iOS version 9.3.5) this is showing like this blank screen:

> [image: Live iPhone 6 image]

Can anyone tell me what is the cause behind it? Some days ago when I tested it was showing fine for device also then I was facing problem of passing the destination address, Now I am facing the problem not loading the Login Screen, Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there can be a delay for the webview to fully load. It looks like there may be a loading spinner in your screenshot (next to the wifi icon). Please try again and see if you can wait for the page to finish loading.

Comment: I have waited an hour still it it not loading, Do you know any other way to fix it?